# How to pass value through link in controller function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to pass value through link in controller function.
 I want to pass below rc value in link so that routes collect it and send to controller.I am new bies in rails.Anyone please help me to solve the problem.

**my html.erb** .which collect value from text box through jQuery function.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var rc=jQuery("#commonid").val();
        </script>

        <div ><%=link_to "Alert By Region",alerts/filter_alert %></div>
```

**my routes.rb**

file which match the link and send to controller

```
match 'alerts/filter_alert', :controller => 'alerts', :action => 'filter_alert'
```

**my controller**

```
          def filter_alert(x)
            @message=x
            @title = @title + ' - Alerts'
            render :site_alerts
          end
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript things belong to Javascript. You need to manipulate this value dynamically upon visitor's clicking this link.

In Rails' controller side, you can't hard code the method. You need to use params from query string because you won't know what the input is.

```
# Views
link_to 'Alert By Region', 'alerts/filter_alert', id: 'alert-link'

# Javascript   
$('#alert-link').on('click', function() {
   var rc = $("#commonid").val();
   if rc {
     this.attr['href'] += '?rc='+ encodeURI(rc);
     return true;
   } else {
     alert 'input is blank!';
     return false;
   }
});

# Controller
def filter_alert
  rc = params[:rc]
  # Then process based on this
end
```